# Angularstrap Timepicker's millisecond timeFormat is one hour off

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timepicker, angular-strap

I am using the timepicker directive of Angularstrap (mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#timepickers) with the number timeformat (milliseconds). When passing an initial ng-model-value in, the representation of this value is one hour off in my opinion. If I pass in 0, the time will be 01:00. In my opinion it should be of course 00:00.

This is my config:

```
angular.extend($timepickerProvider.defaults, {
  timeFormat: "HH:mm",
  timeType: "number",
  minuteStep: 10,
  container: "body"
});
```

See this plunker:
[plnkr.co/edit/B0lWqbhL7AeynyeRE8EG](http://plnkr.co/edit/B0lWqbhL7AeynyeRE8EG)

Am I missing something? Is this indeed the correct behaviour?

Comment: Naively, and not knowing anything about the library, but could "daylight saving" be effecting the value?

Comment: Hmm, I played around with my computer's timezone and I get the desired values for UTC. Looks like I misinterpreted the timestamp a little bit. 0 is just the start of the unix time (01.01.19070) in UTC, which means that it will of course be not 00:00 in my timezone. I somehow left out the date part in my mind and only focused on the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is indeed the correct behaviour. I was forgetting that the numeric value passed in is a COMPLETE date. So the value 0 will be 1970-01-01 00:00:00 in UTC and of course something different in my timezone.